# How to use an Oracle sequence from PHP ODBC function

Tags: php, oracle, odbc

When trying to insert this problem generates me. Use of the undefined constant `SEQUENCE_ID_PROBLEMA` - assumed `SECUENCIA_ID_PROBLEMA`

I do not know where the problem is, please help.

My Oracle sequence:

```
<code>
CREATE SEQUENCE INFORMACION.SECUENCIA_ID_PROBLEMA
 START WITH 0
 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999
 MINVALUE 0
 NOCYCLE
 NOCACHE
 NOORDER;
</code>
```

My code in PHP:

```
<code>
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tabla (ID_PROBLEMA, HORA_INICIO, PROBLEMA, CAUSA, 
      SOLUCION, HORA_FIN, ID_ASIGNACION) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 
$stmt = odbc_prepare($Conex, $sql); 
$success = odbc_execute($stmt,[SECUENCIA_ID_PROBLEMA.nextval,$HORA_INICIO,$PROBLEMA, $CAUSA,SOLUCION,sysdate, $ID_ASIGNACION] );
</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP and SQL are entirely different languages and what you're getting is a PHP warning triggered by the PHP interpreter:

```
define('FOO', 3.1416);
echo FOO; // 3.1416
echo BAR; // Warning: Use of undefined constant BAR - assumed 'BAR' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

Your code tries to handle the sequence name as dynamic input. You cannot use prepared statements for that because the whole purpose of prepared statements is to prevent that from happening. If you really have to, you need to generate the basic SQL skeleton with plain string functions:

```
$table = 'PROBLEMA';
$sequence = 'SECUENCIA_ID_PROBLEMA';
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (ID_PROBLEMA, HORA_INICIO, PROBLEMA, CAUSA, 
      SOLUCION, HORA_FIN, ID_ASIGNACION) VALUES ($sequence.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

```
INSERT INTO PROBLEMA (ID_PROBLEMA, HORA_INICIO, PROBLEMA, CAUSA, 
          SOLUCION, HORA_FIN, ID_ASIGNACION) VALUES (SECUENCIA_ID_PROBLEMA.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

However, your code also tries to feed the dynamic bound variable with a fixed hard-coded text. I wonder if this extra complexity is intentional and necessary. Having different tables with the same exact column names is a potential code smell :)

Comment: I'm trying to do as you say, but it returns this error.                                                Notice: Use of undefined constant nextval - assumed 'nextval'

Comment: Thank you very much @Álvaro González, solve it with triggers in the database

Comment: @JordyMorales You must be doing something you haven't said. There's nothing to "solve" because there's nothing broken. A sequence name is like any other identifier (table or column name), there's nothing special about it and nothing prevents you from using it from PHP or ODBC.

Answer (score -1):

In the end you can not use the sequence from php. What I did was create a trigger in the Oracle Data Bae so that it executes the sequence when insert a new row

```
<code>
CREATE SEQUENCE INFORMACION.SECUENCIA_ID_PROBLEMA
 START WITH 0
 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999
 MINVALUE 0
 NOCYCLE
 NOCACHE
 NOORDER; 

CREATE TRIGGER problema_on_insert
 BEFORE INSERT ON PROBLEMA
 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SELECT SECUENCIA_ID_PROBLEMA.nextval
 INTO :new.ID_PROBLEMA
 FROM dual;
END;
</code>
```

Comment: Sorry but the statement "you can not use the sequence from php" is not correct. A trigger is fine (that's how I use sequences almost every time) but it solves a different problem: to **automate** sequence insertion.

Comment: Yes, first I wanted to use sequence to id autoincrement, but then my brother suggested using the triggers.
I think I did not specify it in the question, I'm sorry